# Does exhausting a card with The Force activate its power?

Tags: star-wars-empire-vs-rebellion

In [Star Wars: Empire vs Rebellion](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite.asp?eidm=265&enmi=Star%20Wars:%20Empire%20vs.%20Rebellion), the card "The Force" says the following:

> Exhaust 1 ready resource card of your choice of either faction.

Does exhausting the card mean that the power associated with the card gets activated, just like how it does if a player normally chooses to exhaust the card?

I could see it going either way. If the power is activated, then it is strategic to activate powers when the player doesn't want it activated (e.g. activating Diplomacy when they have a good hand). However, I can't see any situation when you would want to exhaust a card of your own faction (why not just exhaust that card normally?).

On the other hand, if you don't activate the power, then it would allow you to disable an opponent's card or strategically flip your own character without activating its power. But I'm concerned that this might make The Force a bit too powerful.

I can't figure it out from the rules (it only defines exhausting in terms of using the powers) and the FAQ doesn't describe it. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exhausting is a cost to use an ability.  An ability is not the effect of exhausting.  So if some other effect causes a card to become exhausted, it would not trigger the ability.